# When I push a breakpoint in the java execution code, what does it really do?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

When I push a breakpoint in the java execution code, what does it really do?

Is it a flag at the JVM level? At the processor level?

Can we see the difference in bytecode instructions ? Or is it a loop in the JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find specific reference on setting breakpoints in Java but in native code, debugger would place a single byte interrupt instruction (INT 3) over original instruction. Once reached, interrupt kicks in and gives control to debugger. [This article](http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-debugger-works) has some more information.

From [JVM Tools documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#breakpointCategory) I would infer that similar approach is used in Java bytecode.

Comment: I read the article and I found it really interesting. But I still can't understand everything: in the article, they keep in memory value of selected breakpoint value. Then, change the value at selected breakpoint offset by a bytecode pointing OxCA. This point seems to just sleep.  

It must therefore be considered that the code is already fully loaded in the JVM stack before the execution. And changing the bytecode point, will just change the order of the process ? Don't need to recompile every time when changing something ?

Comment: You don't change your source code but only in-memory bytecode which is already product of compilation. JVM speaks bytecode and knows nothing about compilation. Javac is translator from human made Java source code to JVM bytecode. Any debugging will be occurring in the context of debugger. Debugger will tell JVM to remember replaced code and put breakpoint interrupt (0xCA) in its place. JVM totally knows where in memory this bytecode is sitting, so no problem replacing it.

Comment: And do you know how to tell JVM to remember replaced code and put breakpoint OxCA ?

Comment: That's what JVMTI (JVM tool interface) is for. You use it to ask JVM to place this code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the implementation.  For JITCed code (and, eg, regular C/C++), some boxes overwrite the instruction with a trap instruction, while others make use of "hardware facilities" (generally related to storage protect) to detect hitting the breakpoint.

Similarly in interpreted bytecodes, it can either be a modified bytecode (bytecode code point 0xCA is reserved for this) or by having address compare logic built into the interpreter.

Comment: point OxCA causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period ? It's just a sleep function ?

Comment: 0xCA is reserved to do whatever the JVM wants it to do.  If you patch it into a .class file, however, likely it will be reported as an illegal opcode.